# Why does SWT not show all rows of a Table contained in a ScrolledComposite?

Tags: swt, rcp

I took the attached code from [How to always show vertical scroll bar in SWT table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383916/how-to-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar-in-swt-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), except for the nuber of rows being 4000 instead of 20. In that case I can not go beyond 1416 rows in the table, what is the reason for that ?

```
private static final int MAX_ROWS = 4000;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final ScrolledComposite composite = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Table table = new Table(composite, SWT.NO_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    composite.setContent(table);
    composite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    composite.setExpandVertical(true);
    composite.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    composite.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    Button fillTable = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    fillTable.setText("Fill table");
    fillTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false));

    fillTable.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            if (table.getColumnCount() < 1)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
                {
                    TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
                    column.setText("Column " + col);
                }
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

                for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
                {
                    item.setText(col, "Item " + row + " " + col);
                }
            }

            for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
            {
                table.getColumn(col).pack();
            }

            composite.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        }
    });

    Button clearTable = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    clearTable.setText("Clear table");
    clearTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false));

    clearTable.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            table.removeAll();

            composite.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: It is probably the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851955/2670892) - a limit of 32k on the maximum size. Note that on macOS this code doesn't work at all so if you want to be portable don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greg. While debugging I indeed saw a size of around 32000 pop up all the time when I wanted to see 48000. We don't plan to deploy on a Mac, so that's not a problem. I'll pursue the track where I use the scrollable nature of the Table itself without embedding it in a scrolled composite ...